# jQuery function returns null (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to integrate a jQuery function into my WordPress page. From tests carried out locally it works but not on my WordPress page. The function itself gets the first column value of the row selected from the table and saves it to local storage to be displayed on another page. It does not seem to be an issue with WordPress itself as i have another jQuery function that preforms something similar and it works. I am using the SOGO Web Development plugin to insert java script in the Header and Footer.

Said function is below:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j("#table1 tr").click(function(){
     var b = j(this).children().closest("td").html();
     localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(b)); 
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with wordpress. You should check the structure of your DOM

Comment: And the console for any problems.

Comment: Thanks a million Dekel, you were right.